# change html entities to their respective characters

Tags: xml, perl

I have some XML as output from a website, but when I did xmllint on the XML, I get an error on the `&eacute(;)` character. I want these characters encoded as symbols and also to copy the same data to sql server. Need suggestions on this how can i do this?

Comment: Please post the code you've written so far and some indication of how you're planning to do these various transformations. Please see the StackOverflow guidelines on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and edit your question to provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example of the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: My code is in Perl language. Sorry Ii can't upload the code lines. but I can explain you the scenario. I have used decode_entities() function it works to change HTML entities in their respective symbols but, this function also affects when XML having data other than English language. I want that data as it is with only change in HTML entities by names to it's symbol.

Comment: One more thing I want to clarify, I am inserting this error free XML data to SQL Server 2000 later on. So if their is any function available in SQL Server to change such entities to symbols please suggest that also. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Does the XML have a DTD? If not it's not well-formed, since `&eacute;` is not defined. If it does have a DTD, then you can load it by using the `--loaddtd` option, and use the `--noent` option to replace the entities. You may need to use a catalog if the DTD or one of the files it includes is declared using `PUBLIC`.

Comment: what is DTD? can you explain?

Comment: How about googling for "XML DTD"? If you're working with XML, it would be probably be worth knowing a bit more about it.

Comment: Hi Mirod I am using decode_entities() to change HTML names with its respective symbol, but when I have any other language than English it get failed and change that language too. can you suggest how i can skip that data written in other language and convert only HTML entities? Please suggest Thanks in advance.

Comment: #! /usr/bin/perl -w

use HTML::Entities;
use Encode;

my $a = "&reg; , &ordf; , &Ntilde; , &sbquo; , &icirc; , &ocirc; , &aelig; , &ecirc; , &szlig; , &scaron; , &ugrave;";
my $b = "Pessimo il servizio della climatizzazione. Da migliorare la ristorazione.";
my $c = "先秦兩漢 &reg;&reg;&reg; 儒家 孔子家語 子貢問(疑為「子夏問 曲禮子貢問第四十二";
my $d = "漢字仮名交じり文";
my $e = "Очень хорошо все понравилась";

decode_entities($a);
decode_entities($b);
decode_entities($c);
decode_entities($d);
decode_entities($e);
open(OUT,">test.xml");
print OUT '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>'."\n";
print OUT "<Tag1>$a</Tag1>\n";etc.